# Como modificar el color del campo a los elementos repetidos mostrados en una tabla

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda para poder cambiar de color las filas de una tabla en la pagina solo mientras el numero de póliza y nombre sean iguales.
La tabla ya tiene un estilo pero solo es necesario cambiar el color del campo de cliente y poliza si se tiene el elemento repetido dos o mas veces. He intentado poniendo condicionales pero aun no queda. Gracias

```
<?php
require_once('class/Consultas.php');
$Reportes = new Reportes();

$dato = $_POST['dato'];
$array = $Reportes->getReportes($dato['telefono'], $dato['cliente'], $dato['promotoria'],$dato['FechaI'],$dato['FechaF']);

if(count($array)>0){    

$tabla = '<div class="col-lg-12">
        <img id="export" name="export" src="imagenes/logo_excel.png" style="cursor:pointer"/></td>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive" style="height:600px;">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="Exportar_a_Excel">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="gray" style="color:white;">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>FECHA</th>
                <th>PROMOTORIA</th>
                <th>AGENTE</th> 
                <th>POLIZA</th> 
                <th>NOMBRE</th>
                <th>PRIMA</th>
                <th>TELEFONO1</th>
                <th>TELEFONO2</th>
                <th>ENCUESTADO</th> 
                <th>CODIFICACION</th>
                <th>INTENTOS</th>   
                <th>COMENTARIOS</th>
                <th>AGENDADO</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';


   $contador = 0;
   $lista_colores=array('#F0F0F0','#99CC66','#FF5011');            

   $num_colores=2;
   $indice=0;

   foreach($array as $row){

        $arrayCodf = $Reportes->getCodificacion($row['telefono1'], $row['telefono2'], $dato['codificacion'],$row["fecha"] );

        if($arrayCodf[0]['ea'] == "")
            $codif = "NO CODIFICADO";
        else
            $codif = $arrayCodf[0]['ea'];

        if($arrayCodf[0]['intentos'] == "")
            $intentos = "0";
        else
            $intentos = $arrayCodf[0]['intentos'];

        if($row['encuestado'] == "")
            $encuestado = "NO";
        else
            $encuestado = $row['encuestado'];

        if($codif != "NO CODIFICADO" || $dato['codificacion'] == "0" || $dato['codificacion'] == "TODOS"){
            $color=$lista_colores[$indice % $num_colores];
            $indice = $indice + 1;
            $tabla.= "<tr bgcolor='".$color."'>";

                if($_SESSION['encuesta'])
                    $tabla.= '<td><a href="#" id="ShowEncuesta" data-id="'.$row['iddirectorio'].'" data-nombre="'.$row['nombre'].'">'.++$contador.'</a></td>';

                else
                    $tabla.= '<td>'.++$contador.'</td>';

                $tabla.= '<td><a href="#" id="ShowDirectorio" data-id="'.$row['iddirectorio'].'">'.$row['id'].'</a></td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['fecha'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['promotoria'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['agente'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['poliza'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['nombre'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['prima'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['telefono1'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['telefono2'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$encuestado.'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$codif.'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$intentos.'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['comentarios'].'</td>';
                $tabla.= '<td>'.$row['agendado'].'</td>';
            $tabla.= '</tr>';
        }
   }

   /*
   $dato['cliente'] = $dato['cliente'];

   while ($damefila=mysql_fetch_object($array)){ 
echo "<tr "; 
if ($dato['cliente']>=2) 
    echo "bgcolor=#354648"; //si el resto de la división es 0 pongo un color 
else 
    echo "bgcolor=#ddddff"; //si el resto de la división NO es 0 pongo otro color 
echo ">"; 
   }
   */

   $tabla.= '<tr bgcolor="gray" style="color:white;">
            <td colspan="15" style="font-weight:bold;"  align="center" >Total Reportes : '.$contador.'</td>
          </tr>';
   $tabla.= '</tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>';

   }else{

    $tabla.= '<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                SIN RESULTADOS PARA MOSTRAR
            </div>
          </div>';

   }

echo $tabla;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto pueda ayudar, agrega esto antes de tu primer foreach

```
$duplicados_color = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if(!isset($duplicados_color[$row['poliza'].$row['nombre']])){
        $duplicados_color[$row['poliza'].$row['nombre']] = '#'.random_color();
    }
}
```

y en la parte donde obtienes los colores

```
$color = $duplicados_color[$row['poliza'].$row['nombre']];
```

claro y estas funciones

```
function random_color_part() {
    return str_pad( dechex( mt_rand( 0, 255 ) ), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function random_color() {
    return random_color_part() . random_color_part() . random_color_part();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que en el recorrido de $array haya un contador o un booleano que se incremente o sea true al momento de que preguntes si las pólizas coinciden, luego antes de dibujar la tabla haces que la fila tenga un background.
Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var array=[false,true,false,true];

window.onload = function() {

var tabla=document.getElementById('tabla');
var tab=document.createElement('table');


for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
var tr=document.createElement('tr');
 var td=document.createElement('td');
 if(array[i]==true){
  var texto =document.createTextNode("yes");
  td.className="yes";
 }else{
  var texto =document.createTextNode("no");
  td.className="no";
 }
 td.appendChild(texto);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 tab.appendChild(tr);
tabla.appendChild(tab);
};


};
```

```css
.yes{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='tabla'></div>
```

de acuerdo al ejemplo el siguiente array: `var array=[false,true,false,true];`
representa los datos de tu base de datos, claro solo la columna del cual dependera si tiene que ser o no pintada(ser repetida en tu caso), y haciendo uso de css mediante el nombre de la clase que insertemos `td.className="yes";` y `td.className="no";` lo pintamos de rojo los repetidos(en tu caso) asi:

```
.yes{
    background-color: red;
}
```